# php script connecting to my SQL database

Tags: php, sql, database, cpanel

When trying to connect to my database using PHP I am getting an error.

```
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password") or die ("Couldn't Connect!");
mysql_select_db("databasename") or die ("Couldnt find database");
```

When I try running the script it keeps saying `'Couldnt find database'` which means that I am connecting to the server but my database won't connect.

Am I doing something wrong here? I have pretty much copied and pasted my database name from Cpanel so I know there aren't any mistakes. But in Cpanel it is displayed as 'mywebsite'_database

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using `mywebsite_database` as the database name?

Comment: instead of selecting a db, you could just do a query `show databases;` to get a list of all of them. yours would be listed in there somewhere, and show you the exact name of it, direct from the db's mouth.

Comment: Ye say for example my database name is domain_phplogin thats whay i typed out in the connection and it still didnt show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specify in your question that your database is called:

> 'mywebsite'_database

If this is the case, then you need to change your code to

```
// Connect to the database
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password") or die ("Couldn't Connect!");

// Select the database
mysql_select_db("mywebsite_databasename",$connect) or die ("Couldnt find database");
```

If the above method does not work then I would advise debugging your connection by listing the databases **for that particular user**. Do this like so:

```
// Connect to the database
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password") or die ("Couldn't Connect!");

// Get all the databases for this particular user
$databases = mysql_list_dbs($connect);

// Loop through the databases and write them on the screen
while($database = mysql_fetch_assoc($databases)) {
     echo $database['Database']."\n";
}

exit;
```

Comment: Thanks, i did this but it still says Couldnt find database, is the rest of the code right?

Comment: @BenJShapiro Oh, missed one key thing, check now! :-)

Comment: Yup :-) But I think there may be another issue, I would advise debugging by listing the databases for that particular user. See my edit in 30 secs :-)

Comment: Brilliant thanks ben, Im not getting that error message any more but all i am getting now is a blank page, where as earlier i would get "Please enter a username and a password!"

Comment: @BenJShapiro I have written `exit;` which stops the script from going any further. This is probably why :-)

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_select_db("mywebsite_database")`

Comment: Can you provide any more explanation for your post? This answer is pretty sparse.

Answer (score 0):

Print out the names of all the databases in the server (using **mysql_list_dbs**).

Find the correct database name and replace "databasename" with it.

```
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password") or die ("Couldn't Connect!");

$db_list = mysql_list_dbs($connect);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($db_list)) {
     echo $row->Database . "\n";
}

mysql_select_db("databasename", $connect) or die ("Couldnt find database");
```

I recommend using MySQLi extension as mysql_* is currently in a depreciation process.

I hope this helps

Comment: Can you provide any more explanation for your post? This answer is pretty sparse.

Comment: when i tried this i got, 'information_schema Couldnt find database'

Comment: They are the same answer - glad you got it sorted in the end =)